# validation conflicts with routing

Tags: asp.net

I have a trouble with asp.net validations. At first my validation worked successfully. But when I began to routing, my clientside validations didn't work. There is successful and unsuccessfull codes:

***Unsuccessful  example :***

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.Add("Pages", new Route("{PageName}/", new PageRouteHandler("~/Page.aspx")));
}
```

***Successful example :***

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.Add("Pages", new Route("PageName/", new PageRouteHandler("~/Page.aspx")));
}
```

How can I overcome this problem?